# running python script on a particular program/window in the background?

Tags: python, pyautogui

i made a simple macro using pydirectinput (pyautogui failed me so I had to go with pydirectinput ) but I can't use my computer while the script is running can I like tell python to use this macro script on a specific window/program so I can freely use the computer and the macro will do its stuff in the background?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Adam! Please check out [ask] to include the right information and apply grammar to your question. However, I think it should be possible to run your script in the background. It will help to know what you are running, and how you are running it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the script to run in the background with no window just rename the file extension to ".pyw"

To stop a script that has no window, go into task manager -> details -> locate pythonw.exe -> End Task

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and it's very easy todo!

Just Rename your script's file extension to `.pyw`

`.pyw` files are used in Windows to indicate a script needs to be run using `PYTHONW.EXE` instead of `PYTHON.EXE` in order to prevent a DOS console from popping up to display the output. This patch makes it possible to import such scripts, in case they're also usable as modules.

In Order to close that run file you can just open your "Windows Task Manager" using the shortcut `ctrl + shift + Esc` and then find `pythonw.exe` and click on `DELETE` button or `End Task` Button in Bottom